# Erro na passagem de parâmetro do JQuery pro PHP

Tags: php, jquery

Estou fazendo um modal que tem seu conteúdo de acordo com o link clicado.

Como o conteúdo é carregado do BD, dentro do JQuery de abertura do modal fiz uma chamada em Ajax para um PHP. Nesse PHP farei o acesso ao banco e retornarei uma tabela com os dados. Essa tabela será o conteúdo do modal.

Mas não estou conseguindo recuperar o parâmetro passado pelo Ajax no PHP.

Erro:

```
Notice: Undefined index: idCategoria in C:\xampp\htdocs\canaa\gerarTabelaProduto.php on line 5

Notice: Undefined property: mysqli::$num_rows in C:\xampp\htdocs\canaa\gerarTabelaProduto.php on line 9
```

JQuery / Ajax:

```
$.ajax({
                    url: "gerarTabelaProduto.php",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: {
                        idCategoria: id
                    },
                    contentType: false,
                    cache: false,
                    processData:false,
                    success: function(data)
                    {
                        $("#conteudoModalProduto").html(data);
                    }
                });
```

PHP:

```
<?php

require_once "admin/conexao.php";

$idCategoria = $_POST["idCategoria"];
$nomeCategoria = "";

$categoria = $conexao->query("SELECT * FROM categoria WHERE idCategoria =".$idCategoria);
if($conexao->num_rows <> 0){
   $nomeCategoria = $categoria['nome'];
}

echo $nomeCategoria;
?>
```

Comment: Jquery está no head do **index** ou no arquivo **gerarTabelaProduto.php**?

Comment: Eles estão em arquivos separados?

Comment: O Jquery está no head do index e o gerarTabelaProduto.php é outro arquivo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coloca a opção processData como true:

```
$.ajax({
                    url: "gerarTabelaProduto.php",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: {
                        idCategoria: id
                    },
                    cache: false,
                    processData: true,
                    success: function(data)
                    {
                        $("#conteudoModalProduto").html(data);
                    }
                });
```

Comment: Vlw Diego Machado!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Tente passar como *string*.

Outra dica é ver a requisição pelo navegador. No caso do Chrome ou Firefox tem a aba *rede* que dá pra ver a requisição e os parâmetros sendo passados.

```
$.ajax({
                    url: "gerarTabelaProduto.php",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: {
                        'idCategoria': id
                    },
                    contentType: false,
                    cache: false,
                    processData:false,
                    success: function(data)
                    {
                        $("#conteudoModalProduto").html(data);
                    }
                });
```

Comment: Mesmo passando como String o erro persiste. Tentei passando o parâmetro direto na url, mas o erro continua.

Olhei a requisição de rede e só aparece o 'Query String Parameters (idCategoria = 7)' qd passo o parâmetro pela url. Qd passo pelo 'data' aparece 'Request Payload [object Object]'.

Comment: Bem, passando o parâmetro na URL ele será passado como GET e sim o erro irá persistir. Tente dar um var_dump($_REQUEST) para ver o conteúdo de todas as requisições.

Answer (score 1):

O problema é que você está passando uma variável vazia.

```
data: {idCategoria: id } // Esse id ta vindo de onde??? Ele não foi declarado
```

O correto é você pegar o valor desse ID de algum input ou atributo de alguma tag html, por exemplo: você falou que tem um modal que vai abrir com conteúdo diferente de acordo com o link, então você pode colocar assim:

```
<a href="#modal" class="btn-modal" id="<?php echo $id_categoria ?>">Abrir Modal</a> <!-- Acredito que você gere esses links dinamicamente. -->
```

Ai lah no ajax você pega esse valor da seguinte maneira:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.btn-modal').click(function(){
        var id = $(this).attr('id'); // Agora sim a variável ID tem um valor

        $.ajax({
            url: "gerarTabelaProduto.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                'idCategoria': id
            },
            contentType: false,
            cache: false,
            processData:false,
            success: function(data)
            {
                $("#conteudoModalProduto").html(data);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: O valor da variável está sendo setada antes. Como o problema era na passagem do valor pelo ajax, coloquei apenas essa parte do código.

O problema já foi resolvido com a solução do Diego Machado!

Comment: O valor da variável está sendo setada antes. Como o problema era na passagem do valor pelo ajax, coloquei apenas essa parte do código.

Comment: Desculpa, no código que você colocou não tinha a parte em que a variável foi declarada mas tentei ajudar, espero ajudar na próxima!